# How to watch over SASS to generate compressed as well as expanded or a combination of other styles?

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I am using SASS.

But how to watch over SASS files (*.scss) from the root of the project folder to generate compressed (minified) as well as expanded (prettified) or a combination of other styles?

The reference in the SASS documentation does not seem to be (new) user friendly.

Comment: There's no way to do it by just running the command once and somehow specifying two different styles, but why not just run two commands in two separate terminals?

Comment: @mzgajner, OK so do you mean that there is no option in SASS command line commands where we can combine multiple styles. Right?

Answer (score 2):

If (for whatever reason?) you need both output variants to exist at the same time, you could use a task runner like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and define two different tasks and then run them both at once. You would need to specify two seperate output directories though, otherwise the second task would overwrite the result of the first task, like so:

```
sass: {
    expanded: {
        options: {
             style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {
             'css-expanded/*.css': 'sass/*.scss'
        }
    }
    compressed: {
        options: {
             style: 'compressed'
        }
        files: {
             'css-compressed/*.css': 'sass/*.scss'
        }
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('compile': ['sass:expanded', 'sass:compressed']);
```

Presumably, you probably don't want/need both versions of the css output of the same time though, I guess you want expanded output during development for debugging, and compressed output when building your project? 
If that's the case, you'd still need to specify two sass tasks/targets, but define a separate grunt task for each (but use the same output directory):

```
sass: {
    expanded: {
        options: {
             style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {
             'css': 'sass/*.scss'
        }
    }
    compressed: {
        options: {
             style: 'compressed'
        }
        files: {
             'css': 'sass/*.scss'
        }
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('dev': ['sass:expanded']);
grunt.registerTask('build': ['sass:compressed'];
```

**Edit:**
If you want both version to live in the same output directory at the same time and the output css files don't need the same name for both versions, you could of course use a specific name for one of them `*.css` and `*.min.css`:

```
sass: {
    expanded: {
        options: {
             style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {
             'css-expanded/*.css': 'sass/*.scss'
        }
    }
    compressed: {
        options: {
             style: 'compressed'
        }
        files: {
             'css-compressed/*.min.css': 'sass/*.scss'
        }
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('compile': ['sass:expanded', 'sass:compressed']);
```

Comment: Thanks @FranzHeidl. This explanation is very detailed and helpful. However, I was looking at a SASS -watch kind of solution which is a SASS command line command. However your answer is helpful. But can you confirm that whether we can combine 2 or more styles in sass command itself.

Comment: You won't be able to get two different compilation output styles at the same time using vanilla Sass (or Compass for that matter) from the CLI alone. Sass takes one style option (nested, compressed, expanded, …) and compiles once according to the specified style option.

Comment: In order to get two different kinds of compilates you'll need a task runner to run two different compilation tasks (as outlined above), or, run one compilation task first and one minify/uglify task afterwards (which should be faster than running two compile tasks).

Comment: @FranxHeidl, Yes, this is what I wanted to know.